# E:Type 'e' is not known on line 18 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: package-management

> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> ```
> 'E:Type 'e' is not known on line 18 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list,
>  E:The list of sources could not be read.,
>  E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
> ```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Whats the output of `sed -n '18p' /etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: Try to `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again

Answer (score 0):

First, make a backup of your sources.list file:
`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`

Then, go to this site: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and check the boxes for all the software repositories you want.  (I would use main, restricted, universe, multiverse, security, and updates).

Then, either copy and paste that file into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, overwriting it, or follow the cURL directions on that site (something like 
`curl http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/sources_<some-giant-string>.txt | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list`

It sounds like your sources.list file has a typo somewhere, and this should fix it.

Comment: :( iam so confused iam also new so :(

Comment: Ah, OK, so a quick explanation; sources.list is a list that your package manager (in this case apt-get) uses to keep track of all of the places from which you obtain software.  Usually, this file should be typo-free, but if you ever get third-party software from ppa repositories and you (or a program) are editing it it can be corrupted.  In general, the best way to fix it is just to start over with a clean version of the file generated using an online generator like the one at repogen.  Could you post the contents of your current /etc/apt/sources.list file?  That may be helpful.

Comment: So are you saying the things i downloaded could have messed it up and caused a typo? Can i delete the stuff i downloaded and that will fix it?